# How to dynamically add urls to start_urls

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape product information from amazon and have run into a problem. When the spider reaches the end of the page it stops, and I want to add a way for my program to generically search the next 3 pages of the page. I am trying to edit start_urls but I cannot do this from inside the function parse. Also, this is not a big deal but the program is asking for the same information twice for some reason. Thanks in advance.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy import Request

class ProductSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    product = input("What product are you looking for? Keywords help for specific products: ")
    name = "Product_spider"
    allowed_domains=['www.amazon.ca']
    start_urls = ['https://www.amazon.ca/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords='+product]
    #so that websites will not block access to the spider
    download_delay = 30
    def parse(self, response):
        temp_url_list = []
        for i in range(3,6):
            next_url = response.xpath('//*[@id="pagn"]/span['+str(i)+']/a/@href').extract()
            next_url_final = response.urljoin(str(next_url[0]))
            start_urls.append(str(next_url_final))
        # xpath is similar to an address that is used to find certain elements in HTML code,this info is then extracted
        product_title = response.xpath('//*/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/a/@title').extract()
        product_price = response.xpath('//span[contains(@class,"s-price")]/text()').extract()
        product_url = response.xpath('//*/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/a/@href').extract()
        # yield goes through everything once, saves its spot, does not save info but sends it to the pipeline to get processed if need be
        yield{'product_title': product_title, 'product_price': product_price, 'url': product_url,}
        # repeating the same process on concurrent pages

                                  #it is checking the same url, no generality, need to find, maybe just do like 5 pages, also see if you can have it sort from high to low and find match with certain amount of key words
```

Answer (score 6):

You are misunderstanding how scrapy works here.

Scrapy is expecting your spider to generate (yield) either scrapy.Request objects or scrapy.Item/dictionary objects.
When your spider starts it takes urls from `start_urls` and yields a `scrapy.Request` for every one of them:

```
def start_request(self, parse):
    for url in self.start_urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url)
```

So you changing `start_urls` won't change anything once the spider has started.

What you can do however is simply yield some more `scrapy.Requests` in your `parse()` method!

```
def parse(self, response):
    urls = response.xpath('//a/@href').extract()
    for url in urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(url, self.parse2)

def parse2(self, response):
    # new urls!
```

Answer (score 3):

You can override the `__init__` method and simply pass the URLs with the `-a` option. Please see [Spider arguments](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html?highlight=arguments#spider-arguments) in the scrapy documentation.

```
class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
   name = "quotes"

   def __init__(self, urls=[], *args, **kwargs):
       self.start_urls = urls.split(',')
       super(QuotesSpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Run it like this:

```
scrapy crawl quotes -a "urls=http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/,http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/"
```